# How to POST Multiple API Request with POSTMAN

Tags: json, postman

I am POSTING a request to an API to retrieve information about multiple companies.

I am using the following JSON string to retrieve company information about multiple companies in POSTMAN.

In the example below I'm trying to retrieve information about yahoo and google, however I just keep on getting informaton for Google.

I'm sure I need to add "Value" somewhere, but not sure where.

```
{
  "criteria": {
    "name":"yahoo,google",
    "countryCodes": {
      "mode": "any",
      "values": ["gb"]
    },
    "creditRisk": {
      "values": [
        "VERY_LOW"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Any thoughts?

Comment: Due to [docs](https://app.duedil.com/api/docs#tag/Search/paths/~1search~1companies.{format}/post), name is Registered company name, so probably not list of names, r u sure it should works?

Comment: Hi InDevX, thanks for reaching out. I am very new to POSTMAN, and I guess I assumed there must be a way of selected more than one company name

Comment: It's not postman issue, those man doing his job nice. obviously the problem is in the request/params/api.